# Mostrar el contenido de un gridlookedit mientras se escribe

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

hola amigo y tengo un gridlookedit y estoy trabajan en vb.net con componente en devexpress y quiero  saber como hago para desplegar el cuadro de lista al recibir el foco y cerrarlo cuando se pierda el foco

[image: Desplegar el contenido como se muestra en la imagen sin nesecidad que le click al boton]

De esta manera cargo el combo

```
Private Sub cmb_Nomb_EditValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_Nomb.EditValueChanged

    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = Deduccion.combo_emp(cmb_Nomb.EditValue)
    If cmb_Nomb.EditValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim row As DataRow = Me.cmb_Nomb.Properties.View.GetDataRow(Me.cmb_Nomb.Properties.View.FocusedRowHandle)

        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If row.Item("NO_EMP") = row.Item("NO_EMP") Then
                    txt_Ced.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("CEDULA")
                    txtArea.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("Des_Area")
                    txtCargo.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("Des_Car")
                    txtcargos.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("Cod_Area")
                    txtareas.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("Cod_Car")
                    txtnoemp.EditValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("No_Emp")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola Norma, bienvenid@.Deberias añadir el codigo de ese combobox y lo que has intentado. Has probado los eventos de Focus?  Un saludo

Comment: cual objeto de devexpress estas usando para esto. seguro mas que codigo es una propiedad lo que buscas.

Comment: estoy usando devExpress v.15.2

Answer (score 0):

En el evento GotFocus del GridLookUpEdit utiliza el metodo ShowPopup:

```
Private Sub cmb_Nomb_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_Nomb.GotFocus
    cmb_Nomb.ShowPopUp()
End Sub
```